# Angular + Electron - Cannot find module main.js

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am trying to build macOs app using electron by running `electron-packager . --platform=darwin`

It creates an app but when i run it gives me following error

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/msaadbashir/Downloads/Angular/accounting/accounting-darwin-x64/accounting.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:17)
    at Function../lib/common/reset-search-paths.ts.Module._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:7736:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6116:37)
    at Object../lib/browser/init.ts (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6124:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:20:30)
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:84:18
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:87:10
    at NativeModule.compile (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:287:5)
    at NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:222:8)
    at loadNativeModule (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:23:9)
```

I have done the following apart from installing electron.

index.html `<base href="./">`

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win;
function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff', 
    })
    win.loadFile('./dist/accounting/index.html')
    win.on('closed',function() {
        win = null
    })
}
app.on('ready',createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed',function() {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})
app.on('activate',function() {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "accounting",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "e-ngx-print": "^5.3.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "electron": "^9.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

- set `base-href` to the root folder `npm run electron-build -- --base-href ./`
- be sure the `main.js` in the root
- be sure that in `package.json` main field refers to correct path of `main.js`

Comment: Firstly isn't defining it in index.html the same? Secondly, I did run the command it completes without any error. But nothing happens, as in no window or anything has popped up assuming it was supposed to. It only created the files in dist folder.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. But by npm script you can define the root of your app including main.js while in index.html you can't. If you run by `npm run electron` is everything ok?

Comment: Unable to find Electron app at /Users/msaadbashir/Downloads/Angular/accounting

Cannot find module '/Users/msaadbashir/Downloads/Angular/accounting/main.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry. 

The main.js is currently in src folder

Comment: try `"main": "src/main.js"` in package.json or move `main.js` to the root folder

Comment: yes moved it to root folder and npm run electron worked. And built the package. It is working there too. Could you please reflect this in your answer so I can accept your answer. I am extremely grateful to you for your kind assistance.